# Not able to repeat a Android Animation

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to repeat a particular animation but the animation runs only once and does not repeat itself.

### animation.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale android:fromXScale="0"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="0"
        android:toYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0" />
</set>
```

### MainActivity.java

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private View view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        view = findViewById(R.id.view);

        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation);
        animation.setDuration(6000);
        animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        view.startAnimation(animation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work.

animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="6000">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0"
        android:fromYScale="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1" />
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:toAlpha="0" />
</set>
```

and to handle it in Kotlin

```
    var tex = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.view);
    tex.animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.animation)
    tex.animation?.start()
```

The problem is that you will have to put repetition in both Animations you are repeating the scale application but not the alpha animation.